# Entity Framework migration from existing production database with empty MigrationHistory table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a downloaded production database with an empty MigrationHistory table (contents were accidentally deleted).

I have an updated code model in my development environment (with no previous migrations).

In other words, there's a mismatch between the downloaded production DB schema and the dev environment code model -- and no history between them.

How do I scaffold a code-first migration (or get the SQL) to update the production database to the new model?

I have tried the following, as per the suggestions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx):

1. Enabling migrations in my project (`Enable-Migrations`)
2. Adding an empty migration (`Add-Migration InitialCreate -IgnoreChanges`)
3. Applying this migration (`Update-Database`)

This results in a row being added to the MigrationHistory table.

However, EF seems to think that this means that the current code model matches the database schema (which, of course, it doesn't).

If I try adding a new migration (`Add-Migration UpdatedModel`), this migration comes out empty, which it shouldn't since the code model and the database do not match.

How can I get a code-first migration (or the SQL) that reflects the changes between the code model and the database schema? (If I try doing `Add-Migration InitialCreate` without the `-IgnoreChanges` flag I get the whole database created from scratch, correctly reflecting the code model, but I want the changes.)

Comment: Can you get an older version of your code from source control where the models match the current production database? Failing that you could play with the `MigrationHistory` table, the `Model` column is an actual EDMX file that has been gzipped then Base64 encoded. Not fun though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step in the guide you're following clearly says that you need a model in sync with the DB. That0s wat it's failing.

What you need to do is:

1. temporarily delete the current Code First model (i.e. back up the files of the current model somewhere: file system, CVS)
2. reverse engineer the Code First model from your existing DB
3. enable migrations, and create the initial migration: `Enable-Migrations`

At this step, you have your DB and model in sync. A few more steps and you're ready to go:

4. Replace the model with the original one (the one you kept in the previous step 1)
5. Add a new migration `Add-Migration`
6. Update your DB: `Update-Database`

Tchan! You've got it! By the way, it's important to understand each parameter of the migrations commands, to do so, in your Package Manager Console, use any of this commands:

- `get-help Enable-Migrations -examples`
- `get-help Enable-Migrations -detailed`
- `get-help Enable-Migrations -full`

In few words: when you enable migrations, the Code First model and the DB must match.There is no other way to do it. That's why you must reverse engineer the DB to get the initial synchronization, and work from this point on.